# Magento2 remove object from collection

Tags: magento2, category

Magento2 I am getting the category tree with attributes I need, but it is also printing object, how can I remove this?

[image]

Following is the code

```
$result = $this->getTreeData($this->categoryTree->getRootNode($category), $depth);
        
        $arr[] = $result->debug();

        return $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

class DeleteCustomer
{
protected $_customerFactory;
protected $_registry;

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
                            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_helper = $helper->create();
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

    $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => 3));
    $collection->load();

    $customer = null;
    if($collection->getSize() == 1) {
        $this->_registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $customer->delete();
        echo "customer deleted\n";
    } else {
        echo "no customer found\n";
    }
```

}